# ¿Cómo crear un arreglo de imágenes?

Tags: java, array, java-swing

Estoy intentando crear un arreglo de imágenes que posteriormente debo acomodar a otro arreglo de `JPanel`.

La estructura que tengo hasta ahora es así:

1. Creé un `JPanel`.
2. Dentro de `JPanel` creé otros paneles más pequeños, un arreglo.

Y ahora en esos minúsculos paneles debo colocar una imagen y pensaba hacerme un `JLabel` para colocar los stickers pero se me he complicado la situación.

```
private void PNorte() {
    contendor = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 0, 0));
    panelN = new JPanel[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < panelN.length; i++) {
        panelN[i] = new JPanel();    //Llenamos el array de páneles
        //(6) PROPIEDADES DE LOS CONTROLES 
        panelN[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        //(7) ADICION DE LOS CONTROLES AL CONTENEDOR
        contenedor.add(panelN[i]);
    }
}
```

Las líneas anteriores muestran el arreglo de los paneles al que deseo incrustar imágenes. ¿Cómo podría implementar imágenes a cada casilla?

[image: El resultado de la impresión de los paneles]

Es ahí donde debo colocar imágenes pero hasta ahora no he tenido éxito.

Answer (score 1):

Basado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299495/1065197).

Si tienes las rutas para referenciar a tus imágenes, entonces puedes aplicar algo como sigue:

```
public void agregaImagen(JPanel panel, String rutaImagen) {
    try {
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(rutaImagen));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        panel.add(picLabel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo cargar la imagen.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Y llamas a este método cuando crees tus paneles:

```
for(int i = 0; i < panelN.length; i++) {
    panelN[i] = new JPanel();    //Llenamos el array de páneles
    //(6) PROPIEDADES DE LOS CONTROLES 
    panelN[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    //(7) ADICION DE LOS CONTROLES AL CONTENEDOR
    contenedor.add(panelN[i]);
    //(8) agregar imagen al control (usas comentarios un poco extraños)
    agregaImagen(panelN[i], <ruta de la imagen para este panel>);
}
```

Comment: Entiendo y si lo que quiero es hacer una diferente por cada casilla?

Comment: @angel_elias no entiendo. ¿Quieres una imagen diferente por cada casilla? Entonces provee nombres diferentes donde dice `<ruta de la imagen para este panel>`. Es una variable, puede cambiar de valor con cada iteración. Digamos que tus imágenes se llaman "imagen1", "imagen2" y así, entonces pones que la cadena sea `agregaImagen(panelN[i], "imagen"+(i+1));`. Otra estrategia es que tengas las rutas de las imágenes almacenadas en otro arreglo de la misma longitud y llames al método así: `agregaImagen(panelN[i], rutaImagen[i]);`

Comment: Me parece que tu respuesta es útil, pero no ha funcionado conmigo me  manda error en    ` new file("src/img/imagen.jpg"); ´   y me pide encerrar dentro de una sentencia    try-catch.

Comment: @angel_elias eso es porque el método `ImageIO#read` declara que puede lanzar un `IOException`. Acabo de cambiar el código para adaptarlo a tu necesidad. Ahora, si tu imagen es local al proyecto, sería mejor que utilices un método como `new File(AlgunaClaseDeTuProyecto.class.getResource(resourcePath).getFile())` para obtener el archivo, donde `resourcePath` es la ruta local `/src/img/imagen.jpg` (si vas a usar este método que te explico debes pasar la ruta que comience con /).